# WebDriver: Unable to Click on 'Radio Button'

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have created two sets of code contained in two seperate classes

**Task Required**: need to click on the 'Cash' button on the PH payment page.

1. Class one = simple class, simple code = code works and can click on the cash option.
2. Class two = setup contains page objects, framework uses different structure = code is unable to click on the cash option when reaching the payment page = 'org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: Element not found in the cache'
3. I have used the same locators within both classes but when uses the correct locator in '2' its unable to click on the 'radio' button; as listed above i get the listed error; i have tried to create bespoke methods; using loops etc and different locators but nothing works.

Working code and class:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class TestClass {

    @Test
    public void test() throws InterruptedException {
        //System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\GBruno\\Desktop\\masteringSelenium\\Framework\\src\\test\\resources\\chromedriver.exe");
       // WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        driver.get("http://www.pizzahut.co.uk");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        //click pizza button
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[id='page'] [href='/menu/pizza']")).click();

        //select any pizza to start order
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[class='col-xxs-8 col-xs-6 col-sm-8 col-md-7 col-lg-6'] *> button")).click();

        //enter postcode and find hut
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#ajax-postcode-txt")).sendKeys("TS1 4AG");
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(" #get-store-btn")).click();


        //click start order button
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='store-collection-section']/div[2]/div[4]/div[4]/div/a")).click();

        //add pizza
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='pizza-product-list']/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div/form/button")).click();

        //click mini basket
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/nav/div/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[2]/span[3]")).click();

        Thread.sleep(2000);
        //click checkout
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='divBasket']/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/a")).click();

        Thread.sleep(2000);
        //checkout guest & enter details
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='frmCheckout']/div[2]/div/div[1]/a")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ddlTitleSelectBoxIt']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Mr")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='FirstName']")).sendKeys("Tom");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='LastName']")).sendKeys("Hanks");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='EmailAddress']")).sendKeys("tom_hanks12344566@mail.com");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ConfirmEmailAddress']")).sendKeys("tom_hanks12344566@mail.com");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='PhoneNumber']")).sendKeys("01234 5647890");

        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='btnFindAddress']")).click();

        Thread.sleep(3000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ddlAddressesToChooseSelectBoxItArrowContainer']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("K F C 189-191 Linthorpe Road Middlesbrough TS14AG")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='btnContinue']")).click();

        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='payment-methods']/div[1]/div/label/input")).click();

    }
}
```

**Code dosnt work:**

```
public void selectPaymentTypeAndPayForOrder() throws Exception {
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='payment-methods']/div[1]/div/label/input")).click();

    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(" form[id='CheckoutForm'] input[data-paymentname='Cash']")).click();
```

Comment: check once for frames. If radio button exist in frame then handle with iframes concept.

Comment: thanks @Potnuru Rav

Comment: most welcome dude..!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code resolved the issue:

```
List<WebElement> iframes = driver.findElements(By.tagName("iframe"));
if(iframes.size() == 0) {
    Assert.fail();       
} else {
    // Frames present    
    Assert.assertTrue(true);
}
```